# Xml parsing curiosity - "greater than" in attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have some xml that looks like this:

```
<rootElement attribute=' > '/>
```

This is accepted as well-formed xml by the parsers I've tried it on, and [the relevant part of the RFC](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e888) also suggests this is valid, although I personally wasn't convinced it was until I checked (interestingly enough this wouldn't be valid if it was a opening triangular brace, but it is as a closing brace).

I have some code that is used to "pretty print" xml - it should only change line-lengths and new lines - it shouldn't change any content. However, no matter how I try to parse this xml, it always ends up being entity replaced:

```
<rootElement attribute=' &gt; '/>
```

This isn't entirely unexpected, and any xml parser should treat the two as identical, but for my purposes I don't want this behaviour as this is code meant to change the formatting of an xml file only, not its contents.

It doesn't matter if I load my xml into an XmlDocument:

```
var xml = "<rootElement attribute=' > '/>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Or an XElement:

```
var xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
xElement.Save(Console.Out);
```

Or pass it through a reader/writer pair:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
    streamWriter.Write(xml);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
    {
        xmlReader.Read();
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
    }
}
```

They all replace the `>` entity with a `&gt;`, event though the former is acceptable well-formed xml. I've tried playing with the various `XmlReaderSettings`, or XElement's `LoadOptions`, etc, but all to no avail.

Does anyone know of any way to prevent this?

This is more of a curiosity than an actual issue, but I am interested to see if anyone has any solutions.

[**EDIT to clarify, in the light of some comments/answers**]

I really do realise that this behaviour is expected. In my case, maybe I don't want to use one of the built in xml APIs at all (although whatever I use needs to understand the structure of xml so as not to line break in inappropriate places where it changes the semantic meaning of the document.)

I'm really just interested to know if anyone knows of a way to change the behaviour in these parsers (I expect you can't but figured if anyone knew, they'd probably be on SO), or if anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: Does enclosing the `>` in double-quotes instead of single-quotes yield the same result?  I'm just wondering if there is some reason for escaping one and not the other.

Comment: No - same behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Code like this might change other non-whitespace stuff too. Like the kind of quotes used for attributes.

Comment: @Rob Levine: You wrote _"I don't want this behaviour as this is code meant to change the formatting of an xml file only, not its contents."_ It doesn't. **As long as your consumer properly handles XML**

Comment: @Alejandro - it does from the perspective of a human reading the document. Think of the "pretty print" of "format xml" button in your favourite xml editor. It probably changes line lengths, without turning > into &gt; I understand that "as long as your consumer properly handles XML" they are the same - but they aren't to human eyes and this is code to format the xml for human readability. It isn't meant to change anything other than the line lengths specified by the user.

Comment: @Rob: you're really not getting it at all. Any parser will parse a text representation of XML into an internal representation of XML. There is no good reason for an XML API to retain the original text representation. When serializing again, the original text simply does not exist.

Comment: @John: and yet for all that, all three parsers let you control the behaviour of the semantically meaningless "insignificant whitespace". I appreciate that all three hold a canonical representation and the original format is lost. That still doesn't mean *all* XML APIs definitely behave this way, nor that some don't provide an option to not canonicalise these attribute values. I can certainly conceive of an api setting that lets you specify whether to maintain the verbatim value, even though I don't necessairly expect anyone to implement it.

Comment: @Rob: XML APIs deal with XML. Text in different encodings may be used to serialize and deserialize. There would be no reason to maintain the original text, in the original encoding. Consider: if it's read from a stream, should it keep the stream? If serializing to binary, should it keep the binary around? You're thinking that it has "canonicalized" the text, but it hasn't.

Comment: @John - I'm confused now. I'm talking about "entity encoding" - ie the replacement of '>' with '&gt;', not character encoding. Surely this is *entirely* an issue of xml parsing, and how the representation is stored by the API, and nothing at all to do with the source medium or text encoding.

Comment: @Rob: when the parser parsed the XML, it stored a value for the attribute. This is of type `string`. There is a single `>` character in that string. When it serializes the attribute back into text, it sees that `>` and writes `&gt;`. If you had `&gt;` in the original input, the attribute value would still have a single `>`, which would still be serialized as `&gt;`. The original input is not kept around. That input is not being changed into an entity. The entity is only created when you serialize.

Comment: I understand this point about how it is stored. However, for example when it reads in whitespace it has an option which ignores it, or an option to store the verbatim whitespace. I'm asking, is there a similar option to store the entity verbatim? This point you are making is the same as the first answer by John Skeet which I immediately commented on as probably being right. I fully understand the answer is almost certainly no, and understand how it is "normalised" to a single entity internally. I was just asking the question since a few other areas like whitespace behaviour are controllable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *guess* is that you'll find there isn't a way to change this - as I strongly suspect that the internal representation after loading will be the same whether it's originally `>` or `&gt;`.

Comment: I suspect you are right. In any case, to any parser it makes no difference at all - they mean the same thing. It is just in this rather niche scenario it would be nice to not change it.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing is that `xr.GetAttribute("attribute")` returns `" > "` as you would expect.  My guess is that in the creation of the XML in the `ReadOuterXml` it encodes all `>` as `&gt;`.  So to beat the issue, you would have process each node as it occurred to pretty print it.

Comment: Interesting point. I think that is just because GetAttribute always *decodes* the attribute value - if you have attribute="&gt;" as the attribute value, you get the same behaviour. I suspect, as Jon Skeet suggests, that internally they both have the same single canonical representation and the specific characters used are lost.