# How do I preserve formatting in my merged XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-formatting

I have two XML files that I merge together using the following recursive snippet

```
var resource1 = XDocument.Load(baseFile, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var resource2 = XDocument.Load(targetFile, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

 // Merge per-element content from secondResource into firstResource            
        foreach (XElement childB in secondResource.Elements())
        {
            // Merge childB with first equivalent childA
            // equivalent childB1, childB2,.. will be combined                
            bool isMatchFound = false;
            foreach (XElement childA in firstResource.Elements())
            {
                if (AreEquivalent(childA, childB))
                {
                    // Recursive merge
                    MergeElements(childA, childB);
                    isMatchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if there is no equivalent childA, add childB into parentA                
            if (!isMatchFound) firstResource.Add(childB);
        }

resource1.Save(outputFile);
```

I get a final merged file like I need, however every instance of '>' is replaced with `&gt;`.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's an automatic conversion because the `>` character is a special one in text markup languages. When you read back your XML trough a parser, the `& g t;` will be converted back. It shouldn't really affect... See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665967/xml-parsing-curiosity-greater-than-in-attribute).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Andrei. That's what I assumed as well.